# Reading the RPM with a two pin car inductive sensor and an Arduino

Tags: arduino, inductive

I would like to read the RPM of an old car using my Arduino Nano.

The car has an inductive RPM sensor with two pins, located close to a cogwheel.

I am not very expert on this type of sensor.  With the multimeter, I read a constant 2.5V in DC mode even if I move the crankshaft of the engine manually.

I will attach all the specifications that I have about this sensor in a picture below.

My questions are:

- What is the output of this type of sensor?
- Why there are only two pins?
- How I can interface it with my Arduino?

(The "Ù" stands for Ω)
[image]

Comment: Hyper link the device's data sheet please.

Comment: @Andyaka Unfortunately I do not have the datasheet of the sensor nor the model number, this is all that is written in my car technical user manual.

Comment: It is a fair chance it is a reluctor sensor. A simple comparator circuit can be used to interface with it. For greater angle precision there are specific ics that are used. A Google with search terms like megasquirt reluctor comparator should yield some examples. If your engine is not COP (coil on plug) ignition, it might be easier to use a simple capacitive sensor (a piece of wire) to detect the ignition system. Or if your car has an OBD interface, then cheap interfaces can be bought to extract many variables from the ECU.

Comment: The sensor ought to give negative pulses that increase in amplitude with RPM but not at a slow crank. You then convert the pulses into a 1 shot for full scale RPM by adjusting the pulse width.  That just needs a signal filter to trigger a CMOS 1 shot chip regulated to say 5V. No Arduino required.

Comment: @Kartman I just realized I think is much easier to read the ignition coil signal from the ECU and convert it to RPM with Arduino what do you think about it?

Comment: @Enzo, it depends on the actual vehicle. The ignition signal from the ecu could be logic level or switching the actual coil. What vehicle is it?